# Extract particular string from stream

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I have a file in which snort signatures are stored, I need to extract Bold ones "sid" and CVE number from that signature, here is a sample signature

`alert tcp $EXTERNAL_NET $HTTP_PORTS -> $HOME_NET any (msg:"ET ACTIVEX Possible Microsoft WMI Administration Tools WEBSingleView.ocx ActiveX Buffer Overflow Attempt"; flow:established,to_client; file_data; content:"2745E5F5-D234-11D0-847A-00C04FD7BB08"; nocase; distance:0; pcre:"/]classid\s=\s*[\x22\x27]?\sclsid\s\x3a\s*\x7B?\s*2745E5F5-D234-11D0-847A-00C04FD7BB08.+(AddContextRef|ReleaseContext)/smi"; reference:url,xcon.xfocus.net/XCon2010_ChenXie_EN.pdf; reference:url,wooyun.org/bug.php?action=view&id=1006; reference:bid,45546; reference:cve,CVE-2010-3973; classtype:attempted-user; sid:2012158; rev:2; metadata:affected_product Windows_XP_Vista_7_8_10_Server_32_64_Bit, attack_target Client_Endpoint, deployment Perimeter, tag ActiveX, signature_severity Major, created_at 2011_01_06, updated_at 2016_07_01;)`

> Output:  2012158  [space] CVE-2010-3973

Comment: What have you done so far? Have you tried anything on your own? What is the result, if any?

Comment: I have started building the awk: awk '{for (I=1;I<=NF;I++) if ($I == "refernce") {print $(I+1)};}'  snort.rules    , still I am working on this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ grep -E -o -e 'sid:[^;]+' -e 'reference:cve,[^;]+' file | awk -F '[:,]' '{ sid=$2; getline; print sid, $3 }'
2012158 CVE-2010-3973
```

This uses `grep` to extract the two bits of info from the data that we are interested in.  It does this by using `-o` (to return only the bit of the line that matches the given expressions) and matching the `sid` field and the correct `reference` field. The output of the `grep` command will be

```
sid:2012158
reference:cve,CVE-2010-3973
```

The `awk` program will then read the first line from `grep`, extract the number into the variable `sid`, read the next line and print the stored `sid` and the third field (a field here is anything delimited by either a comma or a colon).

Answer (score 0):

A small modification to @Kusalananda's answer, piping the output of `grep` expression to `cut` seems to work perfectly on my `zsh` shell.

```
grep -o -E -e 'sid:[^;]+' -e 'reference:cve,[^;]+' file | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d',' -f2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
j=`awk '{print NF}' filename`
[root@praveen_linux_example ~]# for ((i=1;i<=$j;i++)); do awk -v   i="$i" '$i ~ /CVE-2010-3973/||$i ~ /^sid/{print $i}' filename;done| awk -F [,:] '{print $NF}'| sed "s/;//g"| sed -n -e '1h' -e '2{p;g;p}'| sed "N;s/\n/ /g"
```

output

```
2012158 CVE-2010-3973
```